# Android keyBoard does not popup when tap in EditText

Tags: android, text, popup

I create a popup and add a EditText for it.But when i tap the text field soft keyboard does not show.How can i do it?
thanks..

Comment: <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="bottom">
<EditText android:id="@+id/dialogSearchBox"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dip" android:hint="Search"
android:inputType="text"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some problem in your xml. Do the below.

Here is popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:gravity="bottom"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <EditText android:id="@+id/dialogSearchBox" 
               android:inputType="text"
               android:hint="Search" 
               android:layout_height="40dip"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent">
     </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you haven't mention that what kind of alert you like to use and whether you like to use any positive or negative button or not.

So, I just inflate this layout to ther alert dialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder pop_up = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
pop_up.setView(this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null));
pop_up.show();
```

On tapping the edit text soft keyboard is showing. Try it.

Comment: You should have find the error in your code on your own. But still when you are unable to find it out , i am pointing it. The problem is you haven't write xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in your xml. Get it now?

Comment: I used this.searchBox
        .setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onFocusChange(View v,
           boolean hasFocus) {
          if (hasFocus) {
           Log.v("[onFocusChange]", ""
             + hasFocus);
           alertDialog
             .getWindow()
             .setSoftInputMode(
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
          }
         }
        }); but not working also.any idea..

Answer (score 0):

Please check the context you are giving to popup. As i have faced the same problem by simply providing context by  getAppContext() method rather then this.

Comment: Thanks.But the context is not an issue.Any idea?